# Convert String to Separate Rows and then to Pyspark Dataframe

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I have a string like this and each row is separated by \n.

I have tried multiple ways but couldn't find any proper way to do it.

Columns Names \n 1st Row \n 2nd Row
For example

```
"Name,ID,Number\n abc,1,123 \n xyz,2,456"

I want to convert it into pyspark dataframe like this

Name     ID   Number
abc      1      123
xyz      2      456
```

Comment: Can you check if below answer worked for you if it did. Accept and upvote the answer.

Comment: Done Manish. Can you please upvote my question.  Don't know why some people have down vote it and now I can't ask new questions.

Comment: Upvoted the question

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try this

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import *
from pyspark.sql.types import *

data = spark.sql("""select 'Name,ID,Number\n abc,1,123 \n xyz,2,456' as col1""")

data.show(20,False)
# +-------------------------------------+
# |col1                                 |
# +-------------------------------------+
# |Name,ID,Number
#  abc,1,123 
#  xyz,2,456|
# +-------------------------------------+
data.createOrReplaceTempView("data")
data = spark.sql("""
select posexplode(split(col1,'\n'))
from data
""")
data.show(20,False)
# +---+--------------+
# |pos|col           |
# +---+--------------+
# |0  |Name,ID,Number|
# |1  | abc,1,123    |
# |2  | xyz,2,456    |
# +---+--------------+

columnList = data.select('col').first()[0].split(",")
data.createOrReplaceTempView("data")

query = ""
for i,e in enumerate(columnList):
  query += "trim(split(col , ',')[{1}]) as {0}".format(e,i) if i == 0 else ",trim(split(col , ',')[{1}]) as {0}".format(e,i)

finalData = spark.sql("""
SELECT {0}
FROM data
where pos > 0
""".format(query))
finalData.show()

# +----+---+------+
# |Name| ID|Number|
# +----+---+------+
# | abc|  1|   123|
# | xyz|  2|   456|
# +----+---+------+
```

Answer (score 1):

I assume you are trying to create from a single text. If so,there are many methods to create a dataframe from lists in pyspark - createDataFrame(), to DF() and parallelize. In python there are many ways to split a string into lists. So combining these two should give you the desired results.Please research them.
One possible method below:

```
tst_str= "Name,ID,Number\n abc,1,123 \n xyz,2,456"
tst_spl = [x.split(',') for x in tst_str.split()]
#%%
tst_df = sqlContext.createDataFrame(tst_spl[1:],schema=tst_spl[0])

tst_df.show()
+----+---+------+
|Name| ID|Number|
+----+---+------+
| abc|  1|   123|
| xyz|  2|   456|
+----+---+------+
```

Comment: sqlContext.createDataFrame(tst_spl[1:],schema=tst_spl[0])
This command is not running

Comment: sqlContext may be different for your environment.. how did you create your sparksession?

Comment: from pyspark import SparkContext, SQLContext

spark_context = SparkContext()


def process(x):
    tst_str = (x[1])
    tst_spl = [x.split(',') for x in tst_str.split("\n")]
    print(tst_spl)
    SQLContext.createDataFrame(tst_str[1:])

rdd = spark_context.wholeTextFiles(r"C:\Users\hasee\Downloads\input_data\*")
rdd.foreach(process)

Comment: Try replacing sqlContext in my code to spark_context. That should work